# PHP | Polish characters - convert UTF-8 to ANSI

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I was trying to converting string UTF-8 to ANSI (Windows-1252).

Here is some examples of my codes:

https://3v4l.org/MDcIj

Non of them doesn't work and polish characters has question marks or diamonts :/

The only solution for now is this library: [CkCharset Converter](https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/charset_convert_file_from_utf8_to_ansi.asp) but i don't want to use such a big library for saving one file.

I'll be grateful for any help with this problem.

The file with script has header like and encoding UTF-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: What are polish characters? I don't think they are in 1252. Why not stay with UTF8?

Comment: `$pl = [ 'ą', 'ć', 'ę', 'ł', 'ń', 'ó', 'ś', 'ż' , 'ź', 'Ą', 'Ć', 'Ę', 'Ł', 'Ń', 'Ó', 'Ś', 'Ż', 'Ź']`

I have to save this string as ANSI to file for billing program who only read this encoding

Comment: Okay, why can't you use UTF8? Those characters aren't available in charset you want. You could possibly use entities if outputting to HTML

Comment: Maybe Windows-1252 isn't correct. But as result I need a file with is saved as 'ANSI'

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ANSI? There are several dozen different "extended ASCII" encodings.

Comment: I use this php extension https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/charset_convert_file_from_utf8_to_ansi.asp

And it's work, but this is extension and i think there is much easier way to do this. 

`include("classes/chilkat_9_5_0.php");
$charset = new CkCharset();


$charset->put_FromCharset('utf-8');
$charset->put_ToCharset('ANSI');
$charset->ConvertFile('file_utf.epp','file_ansi.epp')`

Comment: cannot be done. Use the library. 

```
foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){
        echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."<br>";
}   ```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should *transliterate* the string: replace non-latin characters with the corresponding latin-ascii characters. As far as I know, the most reliable solution is about the usage of \Transliterator from module **intl**.

It works for wide range of languages, including, for example, Polish, Cyrillic or Chinese symbols. I would like to remind you, that the manual replacement of polish symbols will fail for other languages.

I think that this code should work for you:

```
$rule = ':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: Lower(); :: NFC;';

$latinString = \Transliterator::createFromRules($rule, \Transliterator::FORWARD)
        ->transliterate($maybePolishString);
```

You can find more info on INTL documentation page: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Answer (score 0):

If by ANSI you mean the original ASCII encoding that only supports the English letters A-Z, you can use iconv with the `translit` option:

```
php > $txt = "[ 'ą', 'ć', 'ę', 'ł', 'ń', 'ó', 'ś', 'ż' , 'ź', 'Ą', 'Ć', 'Ę', 'Ł', 'Ń', 'Ó', 'Ś', 'Ż', 'Ź']";
php > echo iconv('utf8', 'ascii//translit', $txt);
[ 'a', 'c', 'e', 'l', 'n', 'o', 's', 'z' , 'z', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'L', 'N', 'O', 'S', 'Z', 'Z']
```

If instead you mean [Windows code page 1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), use:

```
iconv('utf8', 'windows-1250', $txt);
```

If instead you mean [DOS code page 852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852), use:

```
iconv('utf8', 'cp852', $txt);
```

You should check which encoding your billing program expects. If it's a DOS program from the 80's, it's probably cp852, but if it's a Windows program from the 90's it's probably windows-1250.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for help.

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1250//IGNORE', $result)
```

Without //IGNORE parametr function returning notice error

```
Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

but it's works just fine :)